# Spring Integration HTTP Outbound Gateway Post Request with Java DSL

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I am trying to consume a rest service and receive a json back and convert it to a list of objects. but I am receiving the below erorr. I am new to EIP and there aren't many tutorials for doing this in java dsl. I have configured 2 channels, one for sending a request and one for receiving the payload back.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'httpPostAtms' is expected to be of type 'org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel' but was actually of type 'org.springframework.integration.dsl.StandardIntegrationFlow'
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:378)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
at org.springframework.integration.support.channel.BeanFactoryChannelResolver.resolveDestination(BeanFactoryChannelResolver.java:89)
at org.springframework.integration.support.channel.BeanFactoryChannelResolver.resolveDestination(BeanFactoryChannelResolver.java:46)
at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.getRequestChannel(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:344)
at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.doSendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:433)
at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.sendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:422)
at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invokeGatewayMethod(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:474)
at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.doInvoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:429)
at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:420)
at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayCompletableFutureProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GatewayCompletableFutureProxyFactoryBean.java:65)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy70.getAllAtms(Unknown Source)
at com.backbase.atm.IngAtmApplication.main(IngAtmApplication.java:25)
```

I am using SI with Spring Boot

```
@IntegrationComponentScan
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
@ComponentScan
public class InfrastructorConfig {

    @Bean
    public PollableChannel requestChannel() {
        return new PriorityChannel() ;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel replyChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel() ;
    }

    @Bean(name = PollerMetadata.DEFAULT_POLLER)
    public PollerMetadata poller() {
        return Pollers.fixedRate(500).get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow httpPostAtms() {

        return IntegrationFlows.from("requestChannel")
                .handle(Http.outboundGateway("https://www.ing.nl/api/locator/atms/")
                        .httpMethod(HttpMethod.POST)
                        .extractPayload(true))
                .<String, String>transform(p -> p.substring(5))
                .transform(Transformers.fromJson(Atm[].class))
                .channel("responseChannel")
                .get();

      }

    }
```

The Gateway

```
package com.backbase.atm.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.integration.annotation.Gateway;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.MessagingGateway;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.Payload;

import com.backbase.atm.model.Atm;

@MessagingGateway
public interface IntegrationService {

    @Gateway(requestChannel = "httpPostAtms")
    @Payload("new java.util.Date()")
    List<Atm> getAllAtms();
}
```

Application Start

```
package com.backbase.atm;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import com.backbase.atm.service.IntegrationService;


@SpringBootApplication
public class IngAtmApplication {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(IngAtmApplication.class, args);
        ctx.getBean(IntegrationService.class).getAllAtms();
        ctx.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `requestChannel` bean name in the gateway definition. Right now you have there an `IntegrationFlow` bean name, but that is wrong.

Always remember that everything in Spring Integration are connected via channels.

Comment: That works!!! when trying to convert the json response to an object after removing the first few characters, I am getting an error  `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity cannot be cast to java.lang.String
 at com.backbase.atm.config.InfrastructorConfig$$Lambda$7/64989209.transform(Unknown Source)` my assumption was that I would be receiving the payload as a string with 'p'. or should the type inference be something else?

Comment: Use `expectedResponseType(String.class)` do not return the whole `ResponseEntity`

Comment: one other thing @Artem. From this article: [link](http://xpadro.blogspot.com/2016/11/spring-integration-mongodb-adapters.html) It says "The name of the input channel is resolved as 'beanName + .input'." which is why I was using the `IntegrationFlow` bean name at first. Is the article mistaken or are they referring to a different scenario?

Comment: Ok! But why don't you use that `.input` suffix anyway? On the other hand you can't do that anyway because you have there a `.from()` pattern. See more here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/wiki/Spring-Integration-Java-DSL-Reference